# How can I remove rectangular brackets around definition optional title?

Tags: errors, theorems, brackets

I am fairly new to latex, so i am using a "base" i got, to write my thesis in. At the beginning of the tex file, the following lines are placed, to define theorems and definitons:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Tétel}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definíció}[section]
```

My problem is, that when i am trying to use it, this happens
Code:

```
\begin{definition}
Az $S\in[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ függvényt \textbf{l-ed fokú spline}-nak nevezzük, ha 
\begin{enumerate}
\item $S\arrowvert_{I_{k}}\in\mathbb{P}_{l} (k\in1..n+1)$
\item $S \in \mathcal{C}^{l-1} $
\item $S$ spline \textbf{interpolációs spline}, ha
 $S(t_{i})=f(t_{i}) \forall t_{i}\in \tau$ alappontra.
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}
```

result:
[image]

my problem is the bracket after the definition
Also i get the following error at the 2nd line

> Something is wrong -- perhaps missing an \item

here is a very minimal version of my document

```
\documentclass[oneside,titlepage,12pt,a4paper]{report}
%\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{t1enc}              
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[active,new,noold,marker]{xrcs}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode} %ezzel összeakadhat \usepackage{algorithmic} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Tétel}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definíció}[section]

\textwidth=6.truein \textheight=9.truein \hoffset=-.5truein
\voffset=-.8truein

\frenchspacing              
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}  
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Függelék}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Függelék}
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sign}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PRD}{PRD}
\DeclareMathOperator{\CR}{CR}
\newcommand{\conj}[1]{\overline{#1}}

\newenvironment{myprogfont}{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}{\par}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textprogfont}{\myprogfont}

\begin{document}

\section{Spline-ok}
\label{sec:Spline}
Ebben a fejezetben a spline-ok és az interpolációs problémák témakörének a dolgozathoz kapcsolódó részeit fogom ismertetni.

\subsection{Alapfogalmak, tulajdonságok}
\label{subsec:Def}

A továbbiakban legyen $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$, ennek $\tau=\{t_{0}, t_{1}, .. t_{n+1}\}$: $a=t_{0}<t_{1}<...<t_{n}<t_{n+1}=b$ egy felosztása. 
$I_{k}:=[x_{k-1}, x_{k}] (k\in1..n+1)$
\begin{definition}
Az $S\in[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ függvényt \textbf{l-ed fokú spline}-nak nevezzük, ha 
\begin{enumerate}
\item $S\arrowvert_{I_{k}}\in\mathbb{P}_{l} (k\in1..n+1)$
\item $S \in \mathcal{C}^{l-1} $
\item $S$ spline \textbf{interpolációs spline}, ha
 $S(t_{i})=f(t_{i}) \forall t_{i}\in \tau$ alappontra.
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I tried your code (in a minimal document -- which you don't provide ;-)) and there are no `[...]` there -- so, whatever you have done, it's not answerable until you provide the document that produces this issue!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i commented with a minimal document below

Comment: What exactly in the setup is placing the number before the definition name?

Comment: \newtheorem{definition}{Definíció}[section] <- the section part right here

Comment: Your code can be compiled without any problem on my system.

Comment: @andesz2x4: Like Bernard I don't have any problems with the code on TL 2015 (Linux)

Comment: do you also get the brackets?

Comment: @andesz2x4 amsthm does not by default write the number before the definition name in the output, so without trying your code (not at a pc) I'm wondering where that come from. The section part normally just controls if a dominant counter should be used.

Comment: @andesz2x4: `no problems` **means** no brackets

Comment: @andesz2x4: If I compile your MWE with XeLaTeX, I also get a compiled output without the problematic `[ ]`, a.k.a. square brackets.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen thank you i will try another compiler

Comment: not relevant to the question, but ... `amsmath` is loaded twice, and since `\amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, it's not necessary to load that separately.  now, regarding the presentation of the theorem-class header, `amsthm` only places the number first if `\swapnumbers` is specified, and that's not done in the example shown, so it must be set somewhere else, and that may be where the extra brackets are coming from.  (which isn't obvious here.)

Comment: I can reproduce the problem running your example with TeX Live 2012, but I also get an error; apparently, the `magyar` option to `babel` is incompatible with `amsthm`. The output is OK with TL 2013 and later. Be aware of the fact that the packages `t1enc` and `newlfont` are largely obsolete. The former should be changed into `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, the latter removed. Also `subfigure` has been deprecated for 15+ years. Update your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue with this minimal document:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definíció}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
Az $S\in[a,b]$
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

but *only* compiling with TeX Live 2012. Here is the console output, note the error message.

```
> /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex andesz.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./andesz.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 piedmontese, polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian
, serbianc, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, u
ppersorbian, welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/magyar.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty) (./andesz.aux)

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 A
      z $S\in[a,b]$
? 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./andesz.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmbxti10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmsy10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on andesz.pdf (1 page, 40242 bytes).
Transcript written on andesz.log.
```

The `magyar` option to `babel` is not compatible with `amsthm` and there's nothing you can do about it, except

1. removing the call to `amsthm`; or
2. updating your (very old) TeX distribution.

The second strategy seems the best. Indeed, there is no problem if I run your test file with TeX Live 2013 or later.

---

### Side notes

You're calling very obsolete packages.

- `\usepackage{newlfont}` and `\usepackage{latexsym}` should be removed
- `\usepackage{t1enc}` should become `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
- `\usepackage{subfigure}` should become `\usepackage{subfig}` (but this requires changing `\subfigure` and `\subtable` into `\subfloat`.

Comment: thank you, i will update my tex. sadly, i need babel magyar for special characters used in hungarian